# WinSxS Installation

Tags: winsxs

Which installer installed the below files, in my system in the `Windows\Winsxs` folder?

```
C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4940_none_10b2f55f9bffb8f8\msvcm80.dll
C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4940_none_10b2f55f9bffb8f8\msvcp80.dll
C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4940_none_10b2f55f9bffb8f8\msvcr80.dll
```

Do I require the same file of version 8.0.50727.5592 or higher than from where I would get it?

Answer (score 0):

Go through *[C Runtime Library WinSxS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcmfcatl/thread/c1dc12ae-f032-4c20-9ff9-c16ea531ca08?prof=required)*.